# Spring @RequestMapping annotation not being picked up

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I've been struggling with this for four hours.

I have a controller defined as such.

```
package handlers.site2;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/site", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public class Site2 {

    public enum Status {
        ERROR
    }

    public static class CommonRO {
        protected Status status;
        protected String description;
    }

    public static class SiteRO extends CommonRO {
        private Integer siteId;
        private Integer companyId;
        private String siteName;
        private Integer siteStatusId;
        private String customerSiteId;
        private Integer timeZoneRuleId; 
    }

    public static class CommonDTO {
        private String authToken;
    }

    public static class SiteDTO extends CommonDTO {
        private Integer siteId;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String index() {
        return "Hello";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getSite", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public SiteRO getSite(Integer siteId, String authToken) {
        SiteRO response = new SiteRO();

        response.siteName = "Test";

        return response;
    }
}
```

a web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>testapp</display-name>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>main.StartUpConfiguration</listener-class>
  </listener>
      <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>Generic Rest API</display-name>
    <servlet-name>GenericRestAPI</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>corewebapi.controller</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GenericRestAPI</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>Apache-Axis Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/AxisServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jws</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>Apache-Axis Admin Servlet Web Admin</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AxisAdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet</servlet-class>

  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisAdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/axis2-admin/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest2/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

and a dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="handlers.site2"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I enabled logging in spring mvc and saw that indeed my controller is being found (so @Controller is being detected), but then I see '[DEBUG] Rejected bean name 'site2': no URL paths identified.' When I try to contact the service using /testapp/rest2/site or /testapp/rest2/site/getSite I get the error message

```
[DEBUG] DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/testapp/rest2/site/getSite]
[TRACE] Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@1c7ab89d] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
[DEBUG] Looking up handler method for path /site/getSite
[DEBUG] Did not find handler method for [/site/getSite]
[TRACE] Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping@3cee5a06] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
[TRACE] No handler mapping found for [/site/getSite]
[WARN] No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/testapp/rest2/site/getSite] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Request: http://:8080/testapp/rest2/site/getSite?siteId=50&authToken=abdf

Other info: Deploying from eclipse to tomcat 6. jdk6 update 45.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your request? Probably the handler method is rejected because the required function parameters cannot be supplied. Do you have security filters configured (doesn't seem so from the configuration posted)? Try removing the parameters.

Comment: It looks like your @RequestMapping of the method index() conflicts the  one on the class.

Comment: @DinoTW How? the index() mapping maps to "/", which should be relative to "/site"

Comment: I remember that the endpoint can be `/site` but `/site/`

Comment: @kpentchev done. I don't have any security defined at all since this is a very simple test.

Comment: @DinoTw I've followed this pattern before. In fact I've followed this pattern for over a year without issue. I'm trying this in a new environment for a new job. One interesting fact is that I'm not using any dependency management because the place I work at is not using maven/ivy and I haven't been here long enough to try to convince them to use something. I basically took the jars downloaded by maven for my personal project (which uses spring mvc + spring data) and dumped it into here.

Comment: @TheBeefMightBeTough, thank you for the clarification. I use Maven to manage the dependency as well. I don't have the setup with me at this moment, so I tried to think the possibility. But it's good that you got it to work.

Comment: @DinoTw Well, I got it to work on for my personal project that has slightly different code and runs on a mac using tomcat 7 rather than 6 and jdk 7 rather than 6. I also use intellij for the personal project. The above code does not work for my work PC. I'm trying to do a POC as to why spring is the way to go for their restful web service (they have their own framework at the moment, and it has *TONS* of ceremony). It doesn't bode well for the framework that I'm having so much trouble :P.

Comment: I'm no expert, but why don't you try minimizing your web.xml file, it seems like you have a lot of stuff in there that could be conflicting with Spring.

Comment: @jlars62 Tried that earlier. No dice. :(

Comment: You forgot to annotate the arguments with `@RequestParam`

Comment: It's not necessary I believe. I rarely use RequestParam unless I need some extra condition such as required = false. My personal mvc project doesn't use @RequestParam and I get the parameters without issue. Notice also that the root path (/site) is not detected, not only /getSite.